# DatePicker формат даты на anko

Tags: android, kotlin

Делаю форму для android на Kotlin  спомощью anko. Нужно чтобы дата на выходе была в формате дд.мм.гггг. Как можно сделать это именно через anko, без помощи класса  Calendar. Сейчас вот такой кастыль

```
onClick {
                    alert {
                        //isCancelable = false
                        lateinit var datePicker: DatePicker
                        customView {
                            verticalLayout {
                                datePicker = datePicker {
                                    maxDate = System.currentTimeMillis()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        yesButton {

                                when {
                                (datePicker.dayOfMonth < 10 && datePicker.month < 10) -> parsedDate = "0${datePicker.dayOfMonth}.0${datePicker.month + 1}.${datePicker.year}"datePicker.dayOfMonth < 10 -> parsedDate = "0${datePicker.dayOfMonth}.${datePicker.month + 1}.${datePicker.year}"
                                datePicker.month < 10 -> parsedDate =  "${datePicker.dayOfMonth}.0${datePicker.month + 1}.${datePicker.year}"
                                else -> "${datePicker.dayOfMonth}.${datePicker.month + 1}.${datePicker.year}"
                            }

                            dateBegin!!.setText(parsedDate)
                        }
                    }.show()
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо костыля

```
parsedDate = "%02d.%02d.%d".format(1,12,2018)
```

Получится

> 01.12.2018

Comment: спасибо, работает